# How to update attribute in array with helm?

Tags: templates, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Values.Yaml

```
env:
  isTest: 'true'
  hostData:
  - isActive: true
    name: a
    url: testA
  - isActive: true
    name: A
    url: testB
```

configmap.yaml

```
test:    
  {{- with .Values.env }}
  hostData: {{ .hostData | toJson}}
  isTest: {{ .isTest}}  
  {{- end }}
```

Now I want to update the url of hostData
I tried to add

```
test:    
  {{- with .Values.env }}
  hostData: {{ .hostData | toJson}}
  isTest: {{ .isTest}}  
  {{- end }}
  {{- range .Values.env.hostData}}
  url: https://{{ .name}}//newName
  {{- end }}
```

But it add the url to the structure of the test

```
test:
  hostData: [{"isActive":true,"name":A","url":"testA"},{"isActive":true,"name":"B","url":"testB"}
  url AnewName
  url BnewName
```

and didn't update the hostData-> url
This is the resuLT I want

```
test:
   hostData: [{"isActive":true,"name":AnewName","url":"testA"},{"isActive":true,"name":"BnewName","url":"testB"}]
```

I tried to create also tpl file and added my logic but the problem that I didn't succeed to return yaml from the tpl

```
{{/*
Create hostData
*/}}
{{- define "get-hostData" -}}
{{- range .Values.env.hostData}}
hostData:
  - isActive: {{ .isActive }}
    name: {{ .name }}
    url: {{ newUrlFromValues }}
{{- end }}
```

The problem that in the config it didn`t return yaml but string

{{- $test1 := include "get-hostData" . }}

maybe I need to return it as json array

Comment: All this yamls don't make any sense. Where does the AnewName come from? Also, it looks like you don't want to update the url fields, but name fields. You say one thing and you provide example of sth totally different.

Comment: I got the name of AnewName  from the value.yaml I want to do it simple. The idea is to update the url in the destination part

Comment: I want to update the URL with new field from the values the idea how to update it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you want to achieve. I assume your goal is to construct the `url` field from the `name` field (although in the provided example you are altering the `name` instead of the `url` (?)). You can do it by updating the `hostData` before converting it to JSON:

```yaml
test: 
  {{- with .Values.env }}
  {{- range .hostData}}
    {{- $url := print "https://" .name "/newName" }}
    {{- $_ := set . "url" $url }}
  {{- end }}   
  hostData: {{ .hostData | toJson }}
  isTest: {{ .isTest }}  
  {{- end }}
```